# how can html run a INO file

Tags: html, arduino

I have a html file which contains a button. And I want to call a INO(Arduino FILE) to run instead of placing the code in browser. How can I call the INO file to run by clicking the button?

code is as following:

Comment: Something is missing here (particularly the CODE). Anyway, you can't execute a ino file in a browser, since a browser can't emulate an arduino (usually). But.. please be more specific and maybe there is some way of implementing the code inside a web page...

Comment: It sounds like you want the button to send a request to the Arduino, which will be acting as a web server. The Arduino should receive the request, run its Arduino code, and the send back some HTML/Javascript output to the person accessing it from the browser.  There's multiple examples of this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771358/how-to-send-http-response-with-json-data-from-arduino-to-web-browser ; http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebServer2 ; and https://grallator.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/json-and-the-arduino-yun/ for examples.